# Rendering Performance Issue IE8

Tags: asp.net, performance, internet-explorer-8, rendering

we have a complex asp.net ajax webapplication, that performes very well in all Versions of Firefox and Safari and IE6/IE7. Since IE8 installation, we have a big performance Issue on all IE8 Browser Machines, that do not have a really powerful Cpu.

Our WebApp is Css 2.1 Compliant. We traced the application and browser with dynatrace and found out that cpu consumption is lost almost completly inside layout rendering and no javascript execution. Every interaction that causes browser to render, results in huge cpu consumption. Hovering over items or style updates for example, forces rendering and takes cpu consumption to 100% on single cpu machines.

In IE8/IE7 Compatibility-Mode application also performs fine. Because rendering is 3 times faster.

Is there any known IE8 problem with some css properties or html tags that can have this impact on IE8 rendering performance?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Would proberbly be a smart idea to link to css file, and perhaps some html.... And you know having done some research yourself.